# excel, saving as display won't go away until clicking 'Cancel'

Tags: microsoft-excel

my code automatically saves my workbook using `SaveAs` into a specified location in the code.

the file saves successfully but for some reason this popup remains until I click 'Cancel'.

have this so far,

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "\\Super\user\workbook.xlsm"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Anyone know any workarounds?

[image]

Comment: Is that a progress bar I see? How big is your file? Are you waiting long enough for it to save properly? You may also want to set `.EnableEvents` and `.ScreenUpdating` to `False`

Comment: Yes a progress bar. 800 kb. Yes I am waiting, it saves properly. Just the progress bar stays there even with `.EnableEvents` and `.Screenupdating` are false.